# Why is Safari not listening to CSS?

Tags: html, forms, css, safari

Does Safari have issues with Media Queries and positioning? My website looks fine in Chrome and Firefox, even looks ok in IE. In Safari, there are weird margins and the forms fall apart. Any ideas on how to fix it? Sorry it's not too specific but I don't know what's causing the issue.

When I change the browser size, things start to move to the right place. It appears to fall apart when it's above 718px in the Contact and Portfolio section.

My website is tiffanymackins.com.

Comment: I have had some issues recently with Firefox adding margins etc and I worked around it by removing default browser styling, e.g in my css I used body {margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: Yeah, I have that in my CSS as well.

Answer (score 2):

use vendor prefixed for display flex and inline-flex, see this:
https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for this. That did fix the flexbox in Safari but broke it in Chrome lol. I only have one display: flex on the entire site.

Comment: can not see it is broken in chrome.

Comment: also add a:
    float:left;
to
    #contact-area input, #contact-area textarea
to have them all line up perfectly and solve the issu in safari

Comment: and ditch the </br> for the textarea, why is that there in the first place, and than float and clear the submit button, so short answer it's not Safari's fault, just recheck your css

Comment: you deserve a drink, my friend. Safari also didn't like an 'important!1 i had in there.